# SQL: Get a limit of records per entity

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have the following setup  (Java/Hibernate/PostgreSQL):

```
TeamName {
  id: Long;
  name: String;
  team: Team;
  ....
}

Series {
  id: Long;
  season: Season;
  dateScheduled: Date;
}

SeriesTeam {
  id: Long;
  series: Series;
  team: TeamName;
}

SeriesTeam {
  id: Long;
  team: TeamName;

}
```

What I want to do is do a select of the past n series (say 10) or the next series from the current date.  Here's what I have so far:

```
select s.* from series s
inner join series_teams st on st.series_id = s.id
inner join team_names tn on tn.id = st.team_name_id
where tn.id in (:teamIds) and s.date_scheduled < CURRENT_DATE
order by s.date_scheduled desc
```

But that is going to get me all the prior series for all teams and I will have to use Java to pick out what I want  How would I go about doing what I want?  Thanks!

EDIT:  For example, say I wanted a limit of 10 per team name, and there are 24 teams, I would want max of 240 records returned to me. (assuming 10 exist before current date)

EDIT2:  Here is the code that I want for a single team:

```
select s. from series s
inner join series_teams st on st.series_id = s.id
where st.team_name_id=85 and s.date_scheduled < CURRENT_DATE
order by s.date_scheduled desc
limit 10
```

I just need to be able to apply this for all the teams....I don't want to make x SQL calls for every team.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.  The syntax is in mysql and you can try it at that site the structure they have is similar to yours.  you can adjust the limit value to change how many from each employee to return sorted by date.  Probably add the current date check there too i guess.

Basically I joined all the needed tables together then created a new column that will tell me if that row is one we should return then added that check in the where clause.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in

```
SELECT e.employeeid, lastname,orderdate, orderdate in (select orderdate from 
orders ord where e.employeeid=ord.employeeid order by orderdate limit 2) as 
good FROM Employees as e join orders as o on e.employeeid=o.employeeid where 
good=1 order by e.employeeid, o.orderdate;
```

for your case:

```
select s.id, s.season_id, s.date_scheduled, st.team_name_id, 
s.date_scheduled in (
    select s2.date_scheduled from series s2
    inner join series_teams st2 on st2.series_id = s2.id
    inner join team_names tn2 on tn2.id = st2.team_name_id
    where tn.id =tn2.id and s2.date_scheduled < CURRENT_DATE
    order by s.date_scheduled desc limit 5
) as foo
from series s
inner join series_teams st on st.series_id = s.id
inner join team_names tn on tn.id = st.team_name_id
where tn.id in (:teamIds) and foo = true
order by st.team_name_id, s.date_scheduled desc
```

Comment: I tried this and that will limit all records, not limit per teamName.  so if I were to get 1000 records across all teamNames, I'd only get 10.  I tried this and that's what happened.

Comment: I updated answer... not sure if the syntax is 100% right but I think that should be do able.

Comment: Let me give it a shot

Comment: So that didn't work.  I got a subset of teamNames that I'm unable to decipher how they got selected.  I had to change the code a bit:  `select * from team_names tn
inner join series_teams st on st.team_name_id = tn.id
inner join (select * from series s where s.date_scheduled < CURRENT_DATE order by date_scheduled desc limit 10) as s on st.series_id = s.id`

Comment: I updated the main post with the code I want for one team.  I just need to apply it for all teams.  Maybe that'd help?

Comment: thanks. I dont' have access to a postgres database right now so it's hard to test.  but here is another attemp XD

Comment: give this one a shot.

Comment: I'm unsure of how to apply this for my setup.  Here's what I have but it doesn't work:  `select s.id, s.season_id, s.date_scheduled, st.team_name_id, team_name_id in 
 (select team_name_id from series_teams st where st.series_id = s.id) as foo
from series s
join series_teams st on st.series_id = s.id
where team_name_id in (82, 85) and foo = 1`.  I need to be able to supply a list of team name IDs and a limit.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried your answer but the results were not as expected.  Series is the parent class, and each series will have 2 series_teams records.  Each series_Team is associated with a single team_name.  For a single team, I'm getting all the series records for each team, in this case its 28 records.  Every record has foo is 'false' with the earliest 6 records set to true.  Any ideas?

Comment: sorry about that on the outer sql you need to check that foo is true.  I think the 6 records is the 6 you want.  sort it by team and date.

Comment: I tried that, but the ones that were marked as true were the earliest records, not the most recent records.  And no matter what number I set for limit, I always got those same 6 as true.

Comment: you might have to post some output... should be just in the "order by s.date_scheduled desc". If you just run the inner query "    select s2.date_scheduled from series s2
    inner join series_teams st2 on st2.series_id = s2.id
    inner join team_names tn2 on tn2.id = st2.team_name_id
    where 82 = tn2.id and s2.date_scheduled < CURRENT_DATE
    order by s.date_scheduled desc limit 5" do you  get the 5 from the latest series that finished for team 82??